# Ajax Sign Up form Plugin wordpress development issue

Tags: wordpress

I am creating my first custom plugin in wordpress named Ajax Sign up plugin. But i am facing problem at the time of creating plugin help me to solve my problem:

```
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'OOPS! No one can access directory directly...' );

register_activation_hook( __FILE__ , array( 'WC_Signup_Form', 'on_activation' ) );
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__ , array( 'WC_Signup_Form', 'on_deactivation' ) );
register_uninstall_hook( __FILE__ , array( 'WC_Signup_Form', 'on_uninstall' ) );

add_action( 'plugins_loaded' , array( 'WC_Signup_Form', 'init' ) );

class WC_Signup_Form {

protected static $instance;
public static function init() {
    is_null( self::$instance ) AND self::$instance = new self;
    return self::$instance;
}

public static function on_activation() {
    if( ! current_user_can( 'activate_plugins' ) ) return;

    $plugin = isset( $_REQUEST['plugin'] ) ? $_REQUEST['plugin'] : '';
    check_admin_referer( "activate-plugin_{$plugin}" );
    # Uncomment the following line to see the function in action
    # exit( var_dump( $_GET ) );
}

public static function on_deactivation() {
    if( ! current_user_can( 'activate_plugins' ) ) return;

    $plugin = isset( $_REQUEST['plugin'] ) ? $_REQUEST['plugin'] : '';
    check_admin_referer( "deactivate-plugin_{$plugin}" );
    # Uncomment the following line to see the function in action
    # exit( var_dump( $_GET ) );
}

public static function on_uninstall() {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'activate_plugins' ) ) return;
    check_admin_referer( 'bulk-plugins' );

    // Important: Check if the file is the one
    // that was registered during the uninstall hook.

    if ( __FILE__ != WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN ) return;
    # Uncomment the following line to see the function in action
    # exit( var_dump( $_GET ) );
}

public function __construct()
{
    # INIT the plugin: Hook your callbacks
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'show_registered_user_details' );
}

function show_registered_user_details()
{
    /* add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position ); */
    add_menu_page( 'User Registration Details', 'Ajax Signup', 'administrator', 'ajax_registration_signup', 'call_user_details', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )."images/users.png", 7 );
}

}
```

> Problem: **i got error like** : Warning: call_user_func_array()
>   expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function
>   'show_registered_user_details' not found or invalid function name in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\blogging\wp-includes\plugin.php on line 496

Comment: Seems like you have not defined the function `show_registered_user_details`

Comment: Hi i defined this function show_registered_user_details()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing the function `show_registered_user_details()` right after `admin_menu` hook like this,

```
public function __construct()
{
    # INIT the plugin: Hook your callbacks
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'show_registered_user_details' );
    function show_registered_user_details()
        {
            /* add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position ); */
            add_menu_page( 'User Registration Details', 'Ajax Signup', 'administrator', 'ajax_registration_signup', 'call_user_details', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )."images/users.png", 7 );
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now its working. can you please help me how i create form with shortcode in wordpress at the same time when plugin activated in frontend so that user fill his details and it save into database and created new table named signup into database for first time.